# How can I program an ATMega328 with the Arduino IDE?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, embedded, microchip, microprocessor

I have my own ATMega328 microcontroller on a breakout board, and I want to program it using the Arduino IDE.

As far as programming goes the schematic looks like it basically just has the microcontroller on there along with a row of header pins to connect to VCC, GND, RXD, TXD, and DTR

Through reading, it seems like I need to burn the bootloader onto the microcontroller before I can upload any real code onto it.

Can I do that with just the serial communication through the USB port, or do I need to use the Arduino as an ISP? I would like to only use the USB communication if possible.

Are there any additional steps I need to follow besides burning the bootloader?

Link to Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V (for reference): https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11114
Link to Arduino Pro Mino 3.3V schematic: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Arduino-Pro-Mini-v14.pdf

Comment: I think Arduino stackexchange might be a better place to ask this. Have you searched for any tutorials on how the Arduino platform works? The Mega328 does not come with a bootloader and you need ISP to program it, and you can use another Arduino as ISP.

Comment: yeah, I would like to not have to use another Arduino as an ISP. I will post this to the Arduino stack exchange as well - thank you!

Comment: Well there is no way around it. You don't have to use an Arduino for the ISP, but you still need to use ISP somehow.

Comment: Basically, you just need a USB-RS232C board and Arduino software ... https://www.electronics-lab.com/project/programming-atmega328p-microcontroller-with-arduino-ide/ … Note you can burn the bootloader as well.